# PySide, open a new window from the running program

Tags: multithreading, widget, window, pyside

Code:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class BrowserDevelopment(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(BrowserDevelopment, self).__init__()
        self.startingUI()

    def startingUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle('Alphabrowser')
        self.resize(800, 400)
        self.statusBar()

        #Menueinstellungen an sich

        menue = self.menuBar()

        #Actions des Menues:
        #datei menue
        menuleiste_datei = menue.addMenu('File')

        datei_exit = QtGui.QAction('Exit', self)
        datei_exit.setStatusTip('Close the programm')
        menuleiste_datei.addAction(datei_exit)
        datei_exit.triggered.connect(self.close)

        #Einstellungen menue
        menuleiste_configurations = menue.addMenu('Configurations')

        configurations_settings = QtGui.QAction('Settings', self)
        configurations_settings.setStatusTip('Configurations(Settings)')
        menuleiste_configurations.addAction(configurations_settings)
        configurations_settings.triggered.connect(self.newwindow)

        self.show()

    def newwindow(self):
        wid = QtGui.QWidget()
        wid.resize(250, 150)
        wid.setWindowTitle('NewWindow')
        wid.show()


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = BrowserDevelopment()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

If you click "Configurations" and then "Settings" a window should pop up, which it does. But it flashes and vanishes. I tried to add a second sys.exit(app.exec_()) but it's not defined since its in another method. Should i just make app global or has this something to do with the so called "threading"? 
Greets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a reference of your new window. Otherwise, it is unreferenced and will be garbage collected.

```
    def newwindow(self):
        self.wid = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.wid.resize(250, 150)
        self.wid.setWindowTitle('NewWindow')
        self.wid.show()
```

Although I would not create the reference in the newwindow method. You could better set up your preferences window in your UI initialization method and then just call self.wid.show()

Comment: Oh hi, thanks for reply. Oh my god, i think i need to reread some stuff about methods. But why wouldn't you make a new method for the window? I did this for more oversight to handle each new window in a seperate method.

Comment: Because this way you are re-creating the window everytime. By placing it in the initialization method (or some other method called suring initialization) you can keep the same reference and just show/hide it anytime you wish. Much faster, less messy and allows you to keep the same object (so that you can for example keep some data in it too).